# How to keep alive another get variables in friendly URLs with ".htaccess"?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm trying to manage friendly URLs with `.htaccess`, it works:

```
RewriteEngine on

Options -Indexes 

<FilesMatch ".*\.(phtml)$">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>


# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?q=$1
```

Works fine when loads `mypage.com/X/Y`; my PHP script converts the string into an array, making each element thereof is each chain is between the slashes founded.

When I add some `GET` vars (for example: `mypage.com/X/Y?var=1`), I can take respective values (`var=1` in example). How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the last line with:

```
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?q=$1 [QSA]
```

Using the [QSA] flag causes the query strings to be combined.

Comment: Nothing changes with [QSA]; i used it in mysite.com/controller/action?var1=test and only takes q=controler/action